# Odoo 9 mail.thread

Tags: odoo-9

I've just upgraded odoo 8 to 9. I know how to add followers when inherit mail.thread in odoo 8 by using message_follower_ids by with odoo 9, it's seem to be changed message_follower_ids relationship into mail.follower instead of res.partner. So I want to ask if anybody know how to add followers in odoo 9. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

message_follower_ids in v8.0 is message_partner_ids in v9.0 .
or you may add partner_id: message_follower_ids.partner_id .
Both work well for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by inheriting the this two items..

```
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin'].
```

and add depend in openerp file

like `'depends': ['mail']`

may it help you..! :-)